# jQuery rating system

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make a rating system from 0, so far I have two classes on and off, there are total of 5 stars,

It would show the rating of the item, until the person hovers over them, then it would hilight the previous stars and hide the current rating,

```
<div id="stars">
<div class="on"></div>
<div class="on"></div>
<div class="on"></div>
<div class="off"></div>
<div class="off"></div>
</div>
```

the JS I got so far

```
$('#stars').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).children().prevAll().andSelf().attr('class', 'on');  
    $(this).nextAll().attr('class', 'on');  
    });
```

Which only hilights all the starts and messes up everything, anyone could help out? Working too many hours and just can't get it to work..

Thanks!

Comment: Helpful comment. I'm looking for a simple solution, most I have worked with are either using JS with images or have a ton of jquery.

Comment: No need for sarcasm especially since you never explained why you're doing this all from scratch.  PPrice's comment is indeed helpful since it links to a fully functional/tested plugin you, or anyone reading this thread, could use straight-away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using this as a preview before a click, then you may want to use the hover function like this:

```
$('#stars .star').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('on');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('on');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('on');
    }
);
```

That goes with the HTML in this jsFiddle where you can see it work: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aRTzQ/

I'd also suggest using `addClass()` and `removeClass()` rather than manipulating the attribute directly as it gives you more flexibility to have other classes on the object and it's more readable.

To make a click sticky so it then remembers that setting, you could use something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QxADg/.  The corresponding CSS/HTML is in the fiddle.

```
$('#stars .star').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('preview');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('preview');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('preview');
    }
);

$('#stars .star').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('on');
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('on');
});

$('#stars').hover(
    function() {$(this).addClass("inPreview");},
    function() {$(this).removeClass("inPreview");}
);
```

Comment: that would work just perfect, but they already have a on or off state on load, is there a way to simply modify this to work with that too? as curently some of them are on and off before the hover

Comment: You'd have to describe how you want it to work in more detail.  Right now, this is "preview-style" code.  It doens't represent an initial state and it doesn't have any mechanism (e.g. a click) to lock in a state.  You'd have to explain how you want all that to work.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, if you see on and off classes in the sample, thats how the code is loaded in, depending on how many stars it has, I would then want the user to be able to hoverover and do what your code does, hilighting the stars, however if they dont click(I will add the handle later on) when user moves his mouse off the stars it would show the same load state, helps? thank you!

Comment: I added a new set of code and fiddle to my answer that shows what you described.

Comment: $(this).prevAll().andSelf().attr('style', 'background:url(\'images/star-on.png\')');
        $(this).nextAll().attr('style', 'background:url(\'images/star-off.png\')');
that worked in the end, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of plugins out there, such as the one PPrice links to. I agree with others that that would be the better way to go unless they don't meet your needs for some reason.

If you want to make this code work or if you're just doing this for the learning, maybe this is what you're trying to do?

You can hover over the "stars" (boxes) to see the colour change.

http://jsfiddle.net/pW3Sn/

```
$('#stars > div').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().attr('class', 'on');  
        $(this).nextAll().attr('class', 'off');  
});
```

Comment: how would I design the out function? like if I didnt vote, and i moved my mouse away?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can implement it using pure CSS.

HTML code:

```
<div id="stars">
    <div class="star">
        <div class="star">
            <div class="star">
                <div class="star">
                    <div class="star"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#stars {
    height: 16px; /* height of stars block */
}
#stars .star {
    height: 16px; /* height of one star */
    padding-left: 16px; /* width of one star */
    background-image: url('http://url.to.your.star.image');
    float: left;
}
#stars .star:hover, 
#stars .star :hover {
    background-position: 0px -16px; /* toggle image */
}
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4CfzD/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use someone's plugin? e.g. http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/